# Default packages in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a simple source of or a reference on which R packages/dependencies are bundled with the installation of RStudio Desktop? For example I am aware that shiny, rmarkdown and knitr (along with pandoc) come with RStudio. I would ideally like to see a full list or if there's a way to search for all the packages.

I've found limited information by going through the historical release notes on the Posit website but was hoping if there's a place where it would be listed in a simple manner.

Comment: If you have a clean install of RStudio Desktop you could run `installed.packages()` ...

Comment: Yes, that is true but I do have the capacity to perform a clean install at the moment. I was hoping for a documentation file that would have that information

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case ...

Comment: Looking at the `.deb` and `.zip` files (from the [download page](https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/)), I can find no R packages "bundled" with the IDE. However, there is a file `r-packages.json` that lists 65 packages, including (oddly, to me) `RJDBC`. Since I had (at one point) RStudio installed and that package is not in my old library, I suspect that's just a helper-list, not a "must install" list (though it does include `rstudioapi`, which is a must-install package, iiuc).

Comment: there's also https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/main/dependencies/common/install-packages#L22-L29 , but that's a much shorter list ...

Comment: I think this question might be better (more quickly, and possibly more authoritatively) answered on the [Posit/RStudio IDE Community forum](https://community.rstudio.com/c/rstudio-ide/9).

Comment: @BenBolker good find, though I'd think since `rstudioapi` is I believe a must-install package, I suspect we'd need to find a list that includes it ... idk

Comment: or [this](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/main/dependencies/common/lockfiles/bionic/renv.lock)  (although now that I look, it seems to be for an outdated version of linux ...)

Comment: Thanks for the responses and links, these are all helpful pointers and is more information than what I started with. I will also try the Posit Community forum